# Sort PopupMenu items by caption

Tags: delphi

I have `TPopupMenu`, items added at runtime. I want to sort em by caption: "Abc", "MyItem", "Zztop". I cannot find Sort method in lists of menu items.

Delphi7.

Comment: Add the items in sorted order to the menue.

Comment: @Sir Assuming there's an opportunity to do that. Consider menu is populated in phases, or by an `Assign` construct, or from an `ActionList`, or maybe it needs to be translated into another language... But OP could certainly be more clear about that!

Comment: @NGLN It is the normal programmers life to build something that solves the problem. If there is a use case for adding in phases and sorting, then you have to build a class that manages the items for sorting, translating and presenting.

Comment: ...like an answer to this question does. @Sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you add the items at runtime the preferred way would by adding the already sorted.
If you have to add items to a menu already containing items you might sort them by setting the `MenuIndex` for the items to the desired value.
An easy way would be to take the Items to a sorted StringList and apply the MenuIndex form the list.

```
Procedure SortMenuItems(Menu: TPopupMenu);
var
  i: Integer;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Sorted := true;
    for i := 0 to Menu.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      sl.AddObject(Menu.Items[i].Caption, Menu.Items[i]);
    end;
    for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      TMenuItem(sl.Objects[i]).MenuIndex := i;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Good. You know same method for SpTbx? `TTbCustomItem` is base class for item and submenu item. No `MenuIndex` in it

Comment: @RProgram sorry, I'm not familiar with SpTbx, do you have the source, maybe you'll find  a Move or similar in the ancestors.

Comment: Found `Move(Previndex, Newindex)`... thks